# Couldn't select folder A/INBOX: NO / [CANNOT] Non-supported characters in mailbox name

Tags: imap, imaplib

I am accessing an IMAP server using Python `imaplib`.
I am doing this for three different mailboxes `box1@mydomain.de`, `box2@mydomain.de`, `other@otherdomain.de`.
In each case, I want to access the folder `INBOX`.
In each case, a folder listing confirms that this folder exists at the top level:

> b'(\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX"'

All three mailboxes are at the same ISP and are accessed via the same IMAP server name.
**The code is working fine for `box2` and `other`.**

For `box1`, however, it fails with this error message:

> Couldn't select folder A/INBOX: NO / [CANNOT] Non-supported characters in the mailbox name

I have determined that `A` will always be the name of the first subfolder:

> b'(\HasChildren) "." "A"'

If I rename `A` to `Z`, the next existing subfolder will take the place of `A` in the error message.

**Question 1:** Why is the server prepending a subfolder when I ask for `INBOX`?

I gather that the error message tells me that the `/` in the name is a problem,
because the server uses `.` as a folder name separator?

**Question 2:** Why is the server so silly to construct a name it will not accept?

**Question 3:** What can I do to repair the mailbox?  (I have no control of that server.)

**Question 4:** Does anybody know a programmer who has ever written code using IMAP and thinks IMAP is a good protocol? (semi-serious question)

Comment: Can we see code?  There's absolutely no reason that it should be choosing A/INBOX if you didn't send that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Max, your request for code did the job. I used the debugger and found the problem in the framework I am using:

I am using a subclass of `mailprocessing.processor.imap.ImapProcessor` that turns what is meant as a command-line tool into an API for my script.

`ImapProcessor`, unless told otherwise, by default uses this logic in its constructor:

```
    # This should catch at least some of these weird IMAP servers
    # that store everything under INBOX. Use --folder-prefix for
    # the rest for now.
    if cmd_prefix is None and root_has_children:
        self.prefix = root_folder
```

and this `root_folder` is simply the first folder in the folder list,
in my case `A`.

If I construct my object as `ImapProcessor(..., folder_prefix="")`, all works as intended.

(Overall, `mailprocessing` has nice functionality, but also a number of weird decisions, plus two bugs to get over.)

So the answers to my questions 1, 2, 3 are "it doesn't", "it isn't", "no repair needed". Instead, my code simply called a functionality I had not expected to exist.